# How to put clear button inside calendar modal in antd datepicker component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, antd

I am using [andt datepicker component](https://ant.design/components/date-picker#examples). In my case, the clear icon covers calendar button.

[image]

I need to remove the clear button and allow to clear manually. (but, as far as I know, currently it can not be done). Or I need to move the clear button inside calendar modal, for instance, next to "Today" button. Is it possible?

I tried to set false value to 'allowClear' property. It removes clear button. But, datepicker value can not be cleared manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderExtraFooter` to customize the footer. Right now there's no option to add more content with `Today` button. But you can hide the current `Today` button and render your custom footer. I rendered a `Today` and `Clear` button in datepicker footer and set `showNow` to false to hide the existing button. You can also check [Extra Footer](https://ant.design/components/date-picker#components-date-picker-demo-extra-footer) example.

Here's the complete code

```
import { Button, DatePicker, Flex } from 'antd';
import dayjs, { type Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', columnGap: '1rem' }}>
            <DatePicker
                ref={ref}
                open={open}
                onOpenChange={setOpen}
                value={value}
                onChange={setValue}
                allowClear={false}
                showNow={false}
                renderExtraFooter={() => (
                    <Flex justify='space-between' style={{ paddingBlock: 7 }}>
                        <Button
                            size='small'
                            type='link'
                            onClick={() => {
                                setValue(dayjs());
                                // Value is not updated if we close the picker immediately
                                setTimeout(() => setOpen(false));
                            }}
                        >
                            Today
                        </Button>
                        <Button size='small' danger onClick={() => setValue(null)}>
                            Clear
                        </Button>
                    </Flex>
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look over docs here for more information: https://ant.design/components/date-picker#common-api

Here's an example:

```
    const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
        const handleChange = (dateValue: any) => {
            setDate(dateValue);
        }
    
        return (
            <>
                <DatePicker
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    allowClear={true}
                    value={date}
                    // clearIcon={
                    //     // you can use every element here
                    // }
                />
            </>
        );
```

You can check how it looks by default: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg6ps.png)

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not solution for my problem. I need to remove clear button and allow to clear manually or move the clear button to another place, for instance, inside calendar modal.

Comment: Basically, you want "Backspace" Key to be used for clearing characters inside the input box ?

Comment: it would be a solution in my case. But, as far as I know, currently it is impossible to clear input using "Backspace" (or "Delete") key